# how to pass a selected array from a uitable to another uitable

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Can anybody guide me how to do something like this:

[image]

I managed to do the 1st & the last screen, I need to put in another 1 in between them.

Is there any tutorial that i can learn from ?

thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in screen1:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    Screen2 *screen2 = [[Screen2 alloc]initWithNibName:.......];
    screen2.itsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];       
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
       {
         screen2.itsArray = yourArrayForScreen2_FirstRow;
       }
    else if(indexPath.row == 2){
         screen2.itsArray = yourArrayForScreen2_SecondRow;
      }else{ ...... }
   [self.viewController pushViewCOntroller .....];
 }
```

in screen2:
NSMutableArray *itsArray; @property and @snynthesize

now use itsArray as you need it. in screen2, do the same as in screen1 for the screen3

Answer (score 2):

Create a uinavigationcontroller with uitableview should help you achieve your goal here.

There are many tutorials for that. A quick google search landed me [this](http://www.shrinkrays.net/articles/monotouch-controllers-by-example/uitableviewcontroller-by-example.aspx). Basically you can use a single navigation controller and a single uitableviewcontroller class and create add the items to them. If you are unable to grasp the concepts from that tutorial add a comment here on where you are stuck. I will try to edit this post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is basically an `NSMutableArray` with `NSMutableArray`

for eg.

**obj1,obj2,obj3...nil is the dict. in your example**

```
NSMutableArray *middleScreenElement1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:obj1,obj2,obj3...,nil];

NSMutableArray *middleScreenElement2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:obj1,obj2,obj3...,nil];

NSMutableArray *middleScreenElement3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:obj1,obj2,obj3...,nil];

NSMutableArray *firstScreen = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:middleScreenElement1,middleScreenElement2,middleScreenElement3];
```

In your 1st TableView,add the following method..

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   NSMutableArray *middleScreenArray = (NSMutableArray*)[firstScreen objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NextTableViewController *nTVC = [NextTableViewController alloc]initWithArray:middleScreenArray];
}
```

now you can use the array to populate your table view just like the middle screen.

**note you have to create an `initWithArray:(NSMutableArray*)array` method in your middleScreenViewController

Hope it helps.. :)